# Order of files being created when installing Firefox

Tags: 14.04, apt, firefox, strace

I would like to find out what file operations are carried out when installing Firefox with apt-get. In particular, is main executable created before other files that are needed to use the browser as intended. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg-deb -c firefox_45.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
```

will show the files in the order the files are processed ...

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/apparmor.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      4984 2016-03-04 12:51 ./etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./etc/apparmor.d/disable/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./etc/apport/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/apport/native-origins.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       103 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/apport/native-origins.d/firefox
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/apport/blacklist.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        59 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/apport/blacklist.d/firefox
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./etc/firefox/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       163 2016-03-04 12:33 ./etc/firefox/syspref.js
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/searchplugins/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/distribution/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/distribution/extensions/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      3373 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:21 ./usr/lib/firefox/
-rw-rw-r-- root/root       899 2016-03-04 14:21 ./usr/lib/firefox/libsoftokn3.chk
-rw-r--r-- root/root    640448 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/0.1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       116 2016-03-04 13:45 ./usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/0.1/clearkey.info
-rw-r--r-- root/root     55184 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/0.1/libclearkey.so
-rw-r--r-- root/root       127 2016-03-04 13:44 ./usr/lib/firefox/dependentlibs.list
-rw-r--r-- root/root    628488 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libmozsqlite3.so
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    252120 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container
-rw-r--r-- root/root     59280 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/liblgpllibs.so
-rw-rw-r-- root/root       898 2016-03-04 14:21 ./usr/lib/firefox/libnssdbm3.chk
-rw-r--r-- root/root       825 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/Throbber-small.gif
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    121040 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/firefox
-rw-r--r-- root/root    232400 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libsoftokn3.so
-rw-r--r-- root/root     18344 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libplc4.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/en-US/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1613 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/en-US/amazondotcom.xml
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1891 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/en-US/ddg.xml
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1245 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/en-US/google.xml
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/common/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       189 2016-03-04 12:33 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/distribution.ini
-rw-r--r-- root/root       569 2016-03-04 12:52 ./usr/lib/firefox/application.ini
-rw-r--r-- root/root    137712 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libsmime3.so
-rw-r--r-- root/root    161760 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libnssutil3.so
-rw-r--r-- root/root    120808 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libnssdbm3.so
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     63456 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/crashreporter
-rw-r--r-- root/root        46 2016-03-04 13:45 ./usr/lib/firefox/platform.ini
-rw-r--r-- root/root      4003 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/crashreporter.ini
-rw-r--r-- root/root    246216 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libnspr4.so
-rwxr-xr-x root/root    141528 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt-stub
-rw-r--r-- root/root    485368 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libfreebl3.so
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      2667 2016-03-04 12:51 ./usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
-rw-rw-r-- root/root       899 2016-03-04 14:21 ./usr/lib/firefox/libfreebl3.chk
-rw-r--r-- root/root  77983480 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       487 2016-03-04 13:45 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/webapprt.ini
-rw-r--r-- root/root     75363 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/omni.ja
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:56 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/extensions/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/defaults/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/defaults/preferences/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        87 2016-03-04 12:33 ./usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/defaults/preferences/vendor-webapprt.js
-rw-r--r-- root/root   8521125 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja
-rw-r--r-- root/root    983960 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libnss3.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/defaults/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       245 2016-03-04 13:46 ./usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/channel-prefs.js
-rw-r--r-- root/root      3786 2016-03-04 12:33 ./usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/vendor-gre.js
-rw-r--r-- root/root     14280 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libplds4.so
-rw-r--r-- root/root    231760 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/libssl3.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1276314 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
-rw-r--r-- root/root        40 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome.manifest
-rw-r--r-- root/root    207840 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/blocklist.xml
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       829 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2472 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default32.png
-rw-r--r-- root/root      4096 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     17225 2016-03-04 10:41 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
-rw-r--r-- root/root  12333896 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/components/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        36 2016-03-04 13:57 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/components/components.manifest
-rw-r--r-- root/root     51240 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/components/libbrowsercomps.so
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       382 2016-03-04 12:33 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/vendor-firefox.js
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/share/pixmaps/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/share/apport/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/share/apport/package-hooks/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     53946 2016-03-04 12:51 ./usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_firefox.py
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:06 ./usr/share/lintian/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:06 ./usr/share/lintian/overrides/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       180 2016-03-04 12:51 ./usr/share/lintian/overrides/firefox
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/share/applications/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      9177 2016-03-04 12:51 ./usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:06 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/share/doc/firefox/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     34975 2016-03-04 12:33 ./usr/share/doc/firefox/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1474 2016-03-04 14:37 ./usr/share/doc/firefox/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       633 2016-03-04 12:51 ./usr/share/doc/firefox/README.Debian
-rw-r--r-- root/root      9380 2016-03-04 12:33 ./usr/share/doc/firefox/MPL.gz
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:06 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:11 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       943 2016-03-04 14:06 ./usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/dictionaries -> ../../share/hunspell
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/distribution/extensions -> ../../firefox-addons/distribution/extensions
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/hyphenation -> ../../share/hyphen
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/searchplugins -> ../../firefox-addons/searchplugins
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins -> ../../firefox-addons/plugins
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions -> ../../firefox-addons/extensions
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/syspref.js -> /etc/firefox/syspref.js
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png -> ../../lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
```

> is main executable created before other files that are needed to use the browser as intended

It is installed fairly at the end and the files after copied after "firefox" also are installed before "firefox" so I would assume yes.

Comment: Which file exactly is the main executable? Could you tell?

Comment: "/usr/bin/firefox" and it is set to an exectuable at the end with "lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2016-03-04 14:08 ./usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh".

Comment: But that is a symlink, not the binary holding code. And shell script it points to is also not the binary holding code.

Comment: sure but "/usr/bin/firefox" is what you start to start firefox. And it is **there** connected to the shell script. /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh is the launher helper. Before that symlink it will not run.

Comment: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" is the main executable, as process monitor tells me. Its not in the menu but if user was insisting, he could run it directly. But point taken, thank you.